# Passing ArrayList from Fragment to Activity and Using BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I am having the following problem, my application has two fragments, one with a Spinner where it contains the contents of the ArrayList and another fragment containing a ListView, I want to pass the contents of the Spinner ArrayList to the Activity to send it to the other fragment, I am doing so because I'm using a BottomNavigationView. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Let's see some code that shows your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

your `Fragment`s have `context`. This context could be casted to your Activity.

in Fragment

```
((YourActivity) getContext()).send(contents);
```